# jQuery Mobile Loading in a function

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

Ive created a function that I use to delete some data. It typically takes about 5-10 seconds or so. I really would like to add a loading spinner to the function.

```
function RefreshDataSubmit() {
    $.mobile.showPageLoadingMsg("a", "Loading");

//Deletes app data
    deleteAppData();

    $.mobile.hidePageLoadingMsg();
}
```

I thought the above showPageLoadingMsg/hide would work however its not ever being displayed.

I'll post the solution if I find it.

Thanks for all the help!

Comment: The answer *completely* depends on the nature of the "deleteAppData" function.

Comment: Did you try this way?

    function RefreshDataSubmit() {
        $.mobile.showPageLoadingMsg("a", "Loading");
        setTimeout(function(){
            deleteAppData();
            $.mobile.hidePageLoadingMsg();
        }, 0);
    }

Answer (score 1):

Let me guess, web kit browsers are not showing **`ajax`** loader.

This is a common problem when **`ajax`** loader needs to be dynamically shown. It can be fixed if **`setTimeout`** function is used to trigger show/hide action.

Something like this:

```
setTimeout(function(){
    $.mobile.loading('show');
},1);
```

and

```
setTimeout(function(){
    $.mobile.loading('hide');
},1);
```

Also you are using deprecated methods, **`$.mobile.loading`** should be used instead.

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/LW7MU/3/

Comment: I tried function RefreshDataSubmit() {
 setTimeout(function(){
     $.mobile.loading('show');
 },1);
 
 deleteAppData();

 setTimeout(function(){
     $.mobile.loading('hide');
 },1);
} and it did not work, am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Yes there's a problem with your code.  $.mobile.loading('hide'); },1); will not wait function  deleteAppData(); to end. Hide method must be placed at the end of deleteAppData(); method. Tell me have you tried to use only setTimeout(function(){ $.mobile.loading('show'); },1); just to see that ajax loader is working?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the scripts that works for me. DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/yeyene/Rdfxs/5/

```
function RefreshDataSubmit() {
    $(".ui-loader").show();
    setTimeout(deleteAppData, 5000);

    //call Deletes app data
    //deleteAppData();
} 
function deleteAppData(){
    // after your scripts, loading will hide, put behind all of your script

    // loading will hide after 5 sec in this example
    $(".ui-loader").hide();
}
```